# how to pre upload file in p-fileupload

Tags: angular, primeng

In my project, I am facing such a situation that i have pre upload one file and show to user ,

```
 <p-fileUpload name="File" #fileUpload customUpload="true" *ngIf="!progress" [files]="uploadMoodelFiles" 
                    (onError)="onError($event)" (onSelect)="onSelect($event)" (onBeforeUpload)="onBeforeUpload()"
                    [showUploadButton]="false" (onClear)="onClear($event)" cancelButtonTitle="Cancel file"></p-fileUpload>
```

i tried get the file which user uploaded previously and stored in one local variable with onselect function,now i have to preupload the file in the uploader again when user come back,i do not know how ,can anyone help.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create file upload instance to access it's `files` property

`@ViewChild('fileUpload') fileUpload: FileUpload;`

Then assign to `uploadMoodelFiles` variable with `this.fileUpload.files`

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablefilter-demo-txrzcc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)